# Quining, but with Windows files!

Tags: code-golf, restricted-source, quine, file-system

Write a quine, that when run, creates itself in the current directory, in a source file named itself. We will be using Windows in this, so the file name (and therefore quine) must have the following limitations:

- None of these characters `\ / : ? * < > |`
- Fewer than <strike>211</strike> 255 characters

#### Limitations and assumptions

- Your code must be a full program (It's going to be run after all).
- No copying from the source file.
- You can assume that there isn't another file with your Quine as its name (as it would produce *Quine* (1)).
- Errors are allowed (as long as they don't get into the source code

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), shortest code in bytes wins!

#### Edit

Maybe I wasn't clear, the file with the name of the quine has to actually contain the quine. My bad.

Comment: What are the limitations on non-ASCII characters in the program? (On Windows, this might quite possibly depend on what language version of Windows is installed; I forget the exact rules and whether they've changed over time.)

Comment: Why fewer than 211 bytes? That's kind of an arbitrary restriction...

Comment: @mbomb007 Max filename size, I believe.

Comment: @VoteToClose It's 255. http://stackoverflow.com/a/265782/2415524

Comment: @mbomb007 Typo, perhaps?

Comment: Why do we have to make it for windows?

Comment: @theonlygusti because i use windows

Comment: I don't know if that have changed but Windows 10 don't accept double quote `"` in file name

Answer (score 6):

## Node.js, <s>56</s> 52 bytes

```
function f(){require('fs').writeFile(f+='f()',f)}f()
```

This prints the warning

> DeprecationWarning: Calling an asynchronous function without callback is deprecated.

If you want the all-green, it costs 4 bytes to change `writeFile` to `writeFileSync`.

Answer (score 6):

## Vitsy, <s>10</s> 27 bytes

```
'rddd++&"rdd8++a[v}v1-D);].
```

If `:` was allowed, I could shorten this to 11 bytes. :(

Explanation:

```
'rddd++&"rdd8++a[v}v1-D);].
'                           Capture all instructions as a string until encountering
                              ' again, looping if necessary.
 r                          Reverse the current stack (output is top-down).
  ddd++                     Push char literal ' to the stack.
       &                    Push a new stack to the stack stack.
        "                   Same as ', but " specific.
         r                  Reverse the current stack.
          dd8++             Push char literal " to the stack.
               a            Push 10 to the stack.
                [        ]  Loop forever.
                 v          Capture the top value as a variable.
                  }         Take the bottom item of the stack and put it on the top.
                   v        Dump the variable to the stack.
                    1-      Subtract 1.
                      D     Duplicate the top item.
                       );   Pop n; if n is 0, exit the loop.
               a[v v1-D);]  This is a makeshift for loop with 10 iterations.
                          . Pop the top stack as n, and the second stack as o. 
                              Write a file called "n" with the contents of "o".
```

The two stacks will be identical at the end. On some Java versions, this may throw a `FileNotFoundException` due to different implementations of the `FileInputStream` class.

#### Previous answer before edit:

```
&'rddd++}.
```

Explanation:

```
&           Push a new stack to the stack stack.
 'rddd++    Modified standard quine.
        }   Move the ' to the right place.
         .  Pop the top stack as n, and the second stack as o. Write a file called
                 "n" with the contents of "o". (Quine name, no content)
```

Because I might as well, here's a diagram of the steps that occur within the stacks (each stack is represented by `[]`):

```
Initial state: [[]]

&              [[], []]
                  Push a new stack to the stack stack.

 '             [[], ["r", "d", "d", "d", "+", "+", "}", ".", "&"]]
                  This stack state occurs because ' will loop around the line
                    until finding the next '.

  r            [[], ["&", ".", "}", "+", "+", "d", "d", "d", "r"]]
                  Reverses the top (last) stack.

   ddd         [[], ["&", ".", "}", "+", "+", "d", "d", "d", "r", 13, 13, 13]
                  Push thirteen thrice.

      ++       [[], ["&", ".", "}", "+", "+", "d", "d", "d", "r", "'"]
                  Because char ' is 39 = 13 + 13 + 13.

        }      [[], [".", "}", "+", "+", "d", "d", "d", "r", "'", "&"]]
                  Takes the bottom item, then puts it on the top.

         .     []
                  Writes a file with content from the second-to-top stack and the
                    name as the concatenation of all elements in the top stack,
                    with top member priority (backwards from my representation).
```

I'm actually not sure how this works right; minute changes cause this to break. For example, placing the `&` in various other locations should work just as well, but it causes `ClassCastException`s, `IOException`s, and `ArrayOutOfBoundsException`s depending on where you put it. I might need to do some bugfixing.

Comment: +1 for `Push a new stack to the stack stack.`

Comment: +1 from me if you can push a new stack stack to a stack stack stack, otherwise forget it! ... Kidding +1, I laughed too.

Comment: @carusocomputing What if I told you I can with `o`? ;)

Comment: Sigh *unzip*...

Comment: @Pavel I have added a stack diagram to demonstrate the creation of stacks within the stack stack, along with the manipulation of individual stacks within the stack stack to make sure that the stacks are stacked correctly.

Comment: Uhm... I think that the generated file is supposed to contain the code (i.e. its content should be equal to its filename)

Comment: @Leo The challenge does not mention this anywhere, I don't think... If that's a requirement, I'll alter it. It'll be a pretty steep bytecount change.

Comment: See revised edit

Comment: @VoteToClose Even after the edit, it's still half the next answer.

Comment: @Thunda No - this puts the source code in the output file as well. Both the stacks are filled at the end with identical contents, which means that the content matches the name, and, as they are both quines, they are all the same.

Answer (score 2):

## Lua, 96 bytes.

```
s="s=%qs=string.format(s,s)f=io.open(s)f.write(f,s)"s=string.format(s,s)f=io.open(s)f.write(f,s)
```

Typed this on my phone, should work, but I'll test it when I get to a computer.

Comment: I think at the very least you'll need to change `sting.format` to `string.format` twice.

Comment: @PeterTaylor you don't like Sting, do you?

Comment: @KeyWeeUsr, I have nothing against him personally, and in fact he helped pay for my upbringing, but I think that the Lua standard library was probably designed for general usability by people familiar with similar APIs rather than specifically for Police fans.

Answer (score 2):

## C, 134 bytes

```
s[255];fd;char p[255]="s[255];fd;char p[255]=%c%s%c;main(){sprintf(s,p,34,p,34);creat(s,0);}";main(){sprintf(s,p,34,p,34);creat(s,0);}
```

Comment: The source here contains `*` so it doesn't look like it's allowed according to the rules.

Comment: @ValueInk Fixed. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 51 bytes

```python
a="s='a=%r;exec(a)'%a;open(s,'w').write(s)";exec(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9FWqdhWPdFWtcg6tSI1WSNRU1010Tq/IDVPo1hHvVxdU6@8KLMkVaNYUwmm4P9/AA)

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>87 79 71</s> 62 bytes

Since windows is not allowing double quote `"` anymore ([more infos](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/naming-a-file#naming-conventions)), I made an other solution verifying the new convention:

```python
w='w=%r;open(w%%w,w[0]).write(w%%w)';open(w%w,w[0]).write(w%w)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v9xWvdxWtcg6vyA1T6NcVbVcpzzaIFZTr7wosyQVLKCpDpNElyvX/P8fAA)